# Make a group be able to run shutdown command without entering a password (CentOS)

Tags: linux, centos, sudo, sudoers

I used the command visudo -f /etc/sudoers to edit the sudoers file.

How do I make a group be able to run the shutdown command without supplying password?

Answer (score 0):

You can often find an example of something like that in the `sudoers` file like looking at the `%wheel` group.  If a "username" field starts with `%` it's treated as a group name.  So you could do something like

```
%<group> ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

To allow any user in `<group>` on any host using that `sudoers` to run `/sbin/shutdown` without a password.  Bear in mind, if there are multiple rules that match, it is the last rule that will "win."

Comment: If you found it helpful you may consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer then